# "make a change" or "make a difference"

Tags: meaning, differences

I was reading a book with tests when I encountered this question:

< "If you quit your job, you'll have to make do with fewer material possessions. Those who've decided to *(make a change/make a difference)* like this don't seem to regret it.

Is there a difference in the meaning between "*make a difference*" and "*make a change*" ?

My guess is that *making a difference* is more than just a simple change and means making a significant change, however *making a change* is referring to just a simple change and nothing more. Am I right guys?

Comment: Yes, "make a difference" means more than making a simple change.  A "change" is, in a way, "input" to the situation, while a "difference" is noticeable "output".  Eg, "If we change the color will it make a difference?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, "make a change" means that you are making something different than how it was. You are CAUSING something.

"make a difference" literally means that the EFFECT is different than the original.

Eg:

*He made a change with his new tactics.* means that he tried differently. He made a cause. It does NOT really mean that his tactics caused an effect. The result might be the same irrespective of his new tactics.
His action is given emphasis.

*He made a difference by changing his tactics.* means that by changing his tactics, something different happened out and it would not have happened if he did not do that.
The result is given emphasis.

Answer (score 3):

Most times, one needs to make a change in order to make a difference, but sometimes, sadly, making a change makes no difference at all.

Comment: Nice comment. Though not an answer.

Comment: Touché, I was hoping the answer would be implied. But perhaps I should've posted a comment instead of answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here, there is a difference between the two choices and the correct answer is "to make a change".

to make a change = to make an alteration.

to make a difference = to have an effect (or no effect) on a person or situation.

> "You won't lose any weight without making changes in your diet.  Substituting pasta for French fries won't make any difference and you won't lose any weight."

Comment: Would you please explain more why you choose "make a change" as the answer?

Comment: @NEO because first you make a change ("quit the job") and then you see if it makes any difference in your life. ("those who decided to do it don't seem to regret." Probably because it made a difference in their quality of life. For the better.) "They decided to make a difference" wouldn't fit here.  Just a matter of semantics, not gramar.